# What transport is used by redis to send receive messages

Tags: performance, tcp, redis, transport

SignalR hosted on IIS. a requirement wants UDP data listener on signalr but being hosted on IIS i couldn't use it as IIS doesn't deals with UDP requests. this made me use redis store for storing UDP data sent by some other server(node/window service). and that data accessed by SignalR hosted on IIS. Redis is faster as said but what transport it use underneath and can it be called as giving clipboard kind of functionality or a sharable memory by applications is the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight TCP

And the answer is so short I have to type this as well!

Comment: Redis can also use Unix Domain Socket if client and server are hosted on the same server.

Comment: Correct, but the windows version is a fork.  I would recommend unix, but I am a Linux fan boy.